# Generate automatic URL alias removing words

Tags: uri, path-aliases

I'm trying to create a topic page for "internet of things", but each time I create the page I notice the URL slug removes the word "of" in it. By default **Generate automatic URL alias** is checked. The only solution I have found is to uncheck the *Generate automatic URL alias* option and giving custom url alias. This is a problem since we have alot pages and it's difficult to update it manually. (Some people who make these pages don't have permission to open drupal and push changes from our website). We also run into an issue with symbols # or + or character 'a'.This is restricting the SEO for pages like C#

Comment: The settings are at /admin/config/search/path/settings

Answer (score 1):

With just the Path module you can only edit each alias one by one manually.

If you want more control than the Path module allows you can use the [Pathauto](https://www.drupal.org/project/pathauto) module. That module has a setting listing all words to exclude from the generated paths. Delete the `of` and `a` from that list if that is what you need. There are also options about how to deal with many special characters under `Punctuation` settings.

Be very careful with the `#` since it has meaning in URLs, it denotes an ID of an anchor on that page.